# Keep only the value in the last non-nan column, set all other values to nan (fast solution)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to convert df into df_target, by keeping only the value in the last non-nan column (for each row individually). The other value should be set to nan.

The following code already achieves what I want, but is very slow for large DataFrames.
Is there any solution that is faster?

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'A': [1, 2, 3, pd.NA, 5],
    'B': [pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA, 4, 5],
    'C': [pd.NA, pd.NA, 3, 4, pd.NA],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

data_target = {
    'A': [1, 2, pd.NA, pd.NA,pd.NA],
    'B': [pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA, 5],
    'C': [pd.NA, pd.NA, 3, 4, pd.NA],
}
df_target = pd.DataFrame(data_target)

df_out = df.apply(lambda row: row.where(row.index == row.last_valid_index(), pd.NA), axis=1)

print(df_out.equals(df_target))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do:

```
df.where(df.notnull().iloc[:,::-1].cumsum(axis=1).le(1), pd.NA)
```

The idea is to count (`cumsum`) the non-NA (`notnull`) from right to left (`.iloc[:,::-1]`) on each row (`axis=1`), then mask everything with `>=2` NA as NA

Output:

```
      A     B     C
0     1  <NA>  <NA>
1     2  <NA>  <NA>
2  <NA>  <NA>     3
3  <NA>  <NA>     4
4  <NA>     5  <NA>
```

Comment: About 2 seconds instead of >2 minutes for my DataFrame, impressive!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.mask(x.index != x.last_valid_index()), axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     A    B    C
0  1.0  NaN  NaN
1  2.0  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  3.0
3  NaN  NaN  4.0
4  NaN  5.0  NaN
```

Comment: This works, but is only slightly faster than my previous code (>2 min for my DataFrame), so I am accepting Quang's solution. Thanks anyway!